# alternating between three different classes in an each loop

Tags: jquery

My current code is setup like this:

```
var accounts = ['gobaopals', 'baopals05', 'baopals02'];
$('.orderId').each(function() {
    var index = $(this).index();
    if (index < accounts.length) {
        $(this).closest('tr').parent().parent().parent().addClass(accounts[index]);
    }
});
```

What Im trying to do is alternate between classes for each table row I have but everything seems to be getting the `gobaopals` class? What is the proper way to `addClass` and cycle through my three classes?

Comment: Just letting you know it exists, there is a pseudo css class for alternating behavior between children. Look for "CSS nth-child"

Comment: You probably need to get the index of the `tr`, not the index of `$(this)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see in the code, the `.index()` method returns the current childs position relative to the parent.

It would seem that if the method is constantly adding the `gaobapals` class, the DOM structure is similar to

```
<div>
  <div class="orderId"></div>
</div>
```

A simple way to implement this is to use a fancy closure

```
var accounts = ['gobaopals', 'baopals05', 'baopals02'];
var index = 0;
$('.orderId').each(function() {

    if (index < accounts.length) {
      $(this).closest('tr').parent().parent().parent().addClass(accounts[index]);
      index += 1;
      index = index % 3;      
    }
});
```